# Oracle HTTP If-None-Match return ETag + Last-Modified

Tags: java, oracle, http, request, header

I'm currently making a request to oracle website to download java from my application and I check if my local file is updated with the If-None-Match tag sending the ETag of the local file. The server return me the ETag in this format: "acd45017cd055c797a331b2f0652d293:1539062148.210488" which is etag:last-modified.

In this case, the server should return 304 but it always return 200 because my local ETag "acd45017cd055c797a331b2f0652d293" doesn't match with the server ETag "acd45017cd055c797a331b2f0652d293:1539062148.210488"

```
protected HttpURLConnection makeConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
    if (!shouldIgnoreLocal() && getTarget().isFile())
        connection.setRequestProperty("If-None-Match", getDigest(getTarget(), "MD5", 32));
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-store,max-age=0,no-cache");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Expires", "0");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
    int status = connection.getResponseCode();
    while (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK && (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)) {
        String newUrl = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
        connection = makeConnection(new URL(newUrl));
        status = connection.getResponseCode();
    }

    System.out.println(connection.getHeaderField("Last-Modified"));
    System.out.println(connection.getHeaderField("If-None-Match"));
    System.out.println(connection.getHeaderField("ETag"));
    System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println(connection.getHeaderField("Last-Modified"));
    System.out.println(connection.getHeaderField("If-None-Match"));
    System.out.println(connection.getHeaderField("ETag"));
    System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
    return connection;
}
```